# Trouble with php syntax for if-loops with css

Tags: php, syntax

I'm not a very good coder, my techniques mostly include copy pasting and editing until it works.

I have this code in my index.php for a joomla 2.5 site, which outputs a certain css style ONLY on the homepage.

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu(); ?>
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()): ?>
<style type="text/css">
  #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works ok, but now I want to use an 'else' statement for all pages that are not the homepage to give an alternate min-height css. This should be easy right? However there's something wrong with my syntax because I can't get it to work. So how should it be written? Thanks

Comment: by the way... there don't exist any `if-loops`, only `if conditions`.

Comment: lol you're right. It sure gives this question a noobie look :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's your not working syntax?

It simply should be an `else:`.

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()): ?>
    #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}
<?php else: ?>
    #contentonderaan {min-height: YOUR_HEIGHTpx;}
<?php endif; ?>
</style>
```

Comment: It's the <style> tags which give me troubles with php. I would try something like:

<?php else; ?>
<style type="text/css">
  #contentonderaan {min-height: 300px;}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: @joskevermeulen No, I mean your try with `else`?

Comment: sorry I pressed enter way too early

Comment: @joskevermeulen Ah ok... It's simply a `:` instead of `;` but the rest is good ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Putting the <style> tags around the whole if-statement would indeed solve my problems. I thought that only css statements should be inside these tags

Comment: @joskevermeulen You can write the <style> twice, but this doesn't reduce redundancy. (And accept the answer when you're able to.)

Comment: I'm definitely going with your code. I'd love less redundancy, I just couldn't get it to work without :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $app = JFactory::getApplication();
 $menu = $app->getMenu(); ?>
<style type="text/css">
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()): ?>

       #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}

<?php else?>

      #contentonderaan {min-height: 100px;} //giving min height 

<?php endif; ?>
</style>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks you! 1 quick question, you almost gave the exact same answer as bwoebi, however he used 'else:', while you use just 'else'. What is the difference here?

Comment: Both are equally same, just different styles thats it . we can use  **:** or **{ }** to cover set of statements in a block. ref:http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Oh ok, but then don't you have to put { } behind your else statement? Since you didn't use ':'

Comment: @joskevermeulen: since its just a single statement within else block, '{}' flower braces are not required .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $app = JFactory::getApplication();
   $menu = $app->getMenu();
   if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) { 
?>
<style type="text/css">
  #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}
</style>
<?php }
else{
 ?>
Some other thing

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use braces:

```
<?php
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu = $app->getMenu();
?>
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()){ ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}
    </style>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <!-- foo -->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu(); ?>
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) { ?>
<style type="text/css">
  #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}
</style>
<?php } else { ?>
<style type="text/css">
  #contentonderaan {min-height: 500px;}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

OR you may also use `else:`

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu(); ?>
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()): ?>
<style type="text/css">
  #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}
</style>
<?php else: ?>
<style type="text/css">
  #contentonderaan {min-height: 500px;}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, your first solution really makes me understand php more! But what exactly does the : do in the second one? What difference is there without :

Comment: It's all about syntax: `if( x ) { some; } else { anonther; }` is the same thing with `if( x ): some; else: anonther; endif;` check: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: I've been on that site before, it just didn't make a lot of sense at the time. Your explanation however is great, thanks, I think I'm getting the hang of it now...

Answer (score 0):

Use shorthand syntax for readability:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()): ?>
    #contentonderaan {min-height: 462px;}
<?php else: ?>
    #contentonderaan {min-height: 642px;}
<?php endif; ?>
</style>
```

Comment: That does indeed look a lot better. In my case it was the only way I could get it to work :)